# Can I upload all data at once in No Man's Sky?

Tags: ps4, no-mans-sky

After discovering a bunch of plants, creatures, outposts on several planets. I found that I had the option to rename and upload, or just upload them.

The problem is I can only upload one at a time. This can be very time consuming, and is a bit annoying. I do enjoy the fact that I can rename everything, but in most cases I just want to upload the base discovered names.

Is there a way to upload all newly discovered data at once?

Comment: Yes, THIS! Especially with the reminder that pops up every 7 seconds, "Upload your stuff!!!"

Comment: FWIW, while bulk upload doesn't seem possible, I find it easier to hold the square button and slowly scroll. That'll allow you to upload a lot of data while not having to press square every time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. It was added in a free patch.

Go to the Menu, Discoveries.

When not on a planet (in space somewhere) you can select the "Upload All" (up arrow) in the bottom left of the screen.

If on a planet, the Discoveries screen shows your current system. Go up a menu from there (right-click on PC) to the Visited Systems screen, and you can use the Upload All button.

[image: Discoveries upload]

Comment: Looks like they moved the button up near the top of the list now (Jan 2021) but it looks the same!

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to upload multiple discoveries at a time, unfortunately. There is an [official blog post](http://www.no-mans-sky.com/2016/08/update-1-03/) which states that they plan to keep updating the game after release though, so hopefully they will add that feature at some point in the future.

Comment: Do you have a link to the reference of what the dev said?

Comment: I think it was in that Reddit AMA. I'll look for it later.

Comment: It was actually from their blog. I edited in the link.